# Load local file into javascript variable from public website

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload, upload

Unlike similar questions, which pertain to javascript running in the browser from a locally opened .html file, I am looking for a solution that works when accessed from a public website, in Sept 2020 after many browsers seemingly have tightened security and accepted answers no longer work.

My use case is I would like the user to select a file via input form, then present them with options to modify the file contents, before uploading it to the server (likely using ajax at this point).

I realize a workaround could be to upload the file as normal to the server, read the file on the server, ajax the content back to the user, have them modify it, then ajax it back to the server. I would like to save one round trip and read the contents of the file directly into a javascript variable the first time, if possible.

From a similar question I found:

```
<input type="file" onchange="this.files[0].text().then(t => console.log(t))" />
```

and this works if I open the .html website from my computer (ie `file://`), however not if I do it from a public domain (`https://`).

Is there another way to do this that still works in latest (Sept 2020) Chrome / Firefox?

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  If you examine the value of the input item, you will see something like `c:\fakepath\filename.ext`, so you won't be able to open the file in any app anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact possible.

I had given up on this. I was sure I would have to upload the file to the server, then send it back to the client via ajax, then process it with the
user, then send it back to the server.

**Pure Javascript**

Not so. I found this link: https://web.dev/read-files/
which describes the following method:

```html
<!-- Copyright 2018 Google LLC.
     SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Read an image file</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" 
          href="https://cdn.glitch.com/9b775a52-d700-4208-84e9-18578ee75266%2Ficon.jpeg?v=1585082912878">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Read an image file
    </h1>
    <input type="file" id="file-selector">
    <p id="status"></p>
    <div>
      <img id="output">
    </div>
    <script>
      const status = document.getElementById('status');
      const output = document.getElementById('output');
      if (window.FileList && window.File && window.FileReader) {
        document.getElementById('file-selector').addEventListener('change', event => {
          output.src = '';
          status.textContent = '';
          const file = event.target.files[0];
          if (!file.type) {
            status.textContent = 'Error: The File.type property does not appear to be supported on this browser.';
            return;
          }
          if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
            status.textContent = 'Error: The selected file does not appear to be an image.'
            return;
          }
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.addEventListener('load', event => {
            output.src = event.target.result;
          });
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }); 
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code above will allow the user to select a image from their HD, then it loads the data into javascript, without sending it to the server, using the FileReader API. I had read elsewhere FileReader didn't work over the network like this, but I was wrong.

If you want to read another kind of file, make sure to call a different method on your FileReader, like `readAsText` for text or even as an array buffer `readAsArrayBuffer`.

The link has more details.

Test on 2020-10-02 on Windows 10

- Firefox 81.0 64-bit
- Chrome 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Edge 85.0.564.68 (Official build) (64-bit)

**React**

Easiest would be to use the `react-dropzone` library https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone
The following from the official docs (MIT):

```js
import React, {useCallback} from 'react'
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone'

function MyDropzone() {
  const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
    acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader()

      reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted')
      reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed')
      reader.onload = () => {
      // Do whatever you want with the file contents
        const binaryStr = reader.result
        console.log(binaryStr)
      }
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
    })
    
  }, [])
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({onDrop})

  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```